# How to resample

Tags: python, regression

I have to deal with a small dataset. I thought that I maght take advantage of resamplin methods to enlarge the population and improve the performance of my regression algorithm. I heard about SMOTE, but it is used for classification in imbalanced datasets. Is there any method to create synthetic data of a small size dataset? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

please check out library **imbalanced-learn** (python).
Have you some example of code:

```
#assuming that you have X and y

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

smote = SMOTE(ratio='minority')
X_sm, y_sm = smote.fit_sample(X, y)
```

Documentation:

https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.TomekLinks.html

https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by others, use oversampling SMOTE, it will balance your data set and create more examples(based on neighbors) equals to your majority class.

Comment: "majority class" doesn't exist, Question is about regression

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Bootstrapped regression](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/sta305files/FoxOnBootingRegInR.pdf).

Answer (score -3):

You can also try the [GAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network)'s to generate some pseudo data.